# Create a world map in R studio

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

For a paper on paper publishing locations around the world, I need to create a map where those places are clearly indicated on the map. I would like it to be as pretty as possible since it's for a scientific publication.

So far I used "elevatr" package and I produced a nice topographic map. What I'm afraid with that one is that the focus is taken away from my subject: here's the code I used:

Version: Version 2023.03.1+446 (2023.03.1+446)

```
#libraries
libs <- c("elevatr", "terra", "tidyverse", 
          "sf", "giscoR", "marmap")

installed_libs <- libs %in% rownames(installed.packages())
if (any(installed_libs == F)) {
  install.packages(libs[!installed_libs])
}

invisible(lapply(libs, library, character.only = T))

#1. GET WORLD MAP

crsLONGLAT <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"

get_sf <- function() {
  world_sf <- giscoR::gisco_get_countries(
    year = "2016",
    epsg = "4326",
    resolution = "10"
  )
  
  world_transformed <- st_transform(world_sf, crs = crsLONGLAT)
  
  return(world_transformed)
}

world_transformed <- get_sf()

# 2. GET ELEVATION DATA

get_elevation_data <- function(world_elevation, world_elevation_df) {
  
  world_elevation <- get_elev_raster(
    locations = world_transformed, 
    z = 3, 
    clip = "locations") 
  
  world_elevation_df <- as.data.frame(world_elevation, xy = T) %>%
    na.omit()
  
  colnames(world_elevation_df)[3] <- "elevation"
  
  return(world_elevation_df)
}

world_elevation_df <- get_elevation_data()


# 3. MAP
library(marmap)
get_elevation_map <- function(world_map) {
  
  world_map <- ggplot() +
    geom_tile(data = world_elevation_df, 
              aes(x = x, y = y, fill = elevation)) +
    scale_fill_etopo() +
    coord_sf(crs = crsLONGLAT)+
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(text = element_text(family = "georg", color = "#22211d"),
          axis.line = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          legend.position = "none",
          panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "white", size = 0.2),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          plot.title = element_text(size=18, color="grey20", hjust=1, vjust=-5),
          plot.caption = element_text(size=8, color="grey70", hjust=.15, vjust=20),
          plot.margin = unit(c(t=0, r=0, b=0, l=0),"lines"), #added these narrower margins to enlarge maps
          plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = NA), 
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = NA),
          panel.border = element_blank()) +
    labs(x = "", 
         y = NULL, 
         title = "Topographic map world", 
         subtitle = "", 
         caption = "CRD")
  
  return(world_map)
}

world_map <- get_elevation_map()
#world_map
ggsave(filename="world_topo_map.png", width=7, height=8.5, dpi = 600, device='png', world_map)
```

I also used a simple map using ggplot. Here's the code I used:
world_coordinates <- map_data("world")

```
ggplot() + geom_map(
    data = world_coordinates, map = world_coordinates,
    aes(x = x, y = y, map_id = region),
    color = "white", fill = "lightgray", size = 0.1  ) + 
geom_point(
    data = duse_cut,
    aes(x, y, fill="#e672f4"), # dark blue
    alpha = 0.7) +
    theme_bw() + 
    theme(legend.position="none")
```

Any suggestion on a world map that I could use?